# transform a jpg into png and make a color transparent in it

Tags: php, image, png, transparency, gd

In PHP I'm trying to process an image, that is, I'm trying to make the surrounding color transparent in a jpg file. I'm using the GD library by the way.

I can directly output the image by converting it into a png using imagecreatefromjpeg and imagepng functions. But I can't find a way to make the specified color transparent. Also, some images have lighter gray artifacts around black graphics, created during saving. Is there any way I can include those as well?

I'm kind of lost. I found some answers to make a color transparent on an image but I don't know how to first convert the image without saving it into the server and then process it.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's my code so far. I managed to make a specified color transparent but I can't make it detect the surrounding one yet.

Most of the time images will be closed because they'l be logos or texts, saved in the allowed image formats. So I don't think I will have a major issue with gradients but it would be great if I could manage to manipulate transparency in the surrounding gradients, if any, such as drop shadows.

Is there also any way to detect if the png/gif image is already transparent? My code paints the transparent parts into black for those files now.

```
$file = 'images/18.jpg';
$specs = getimagesize($file);

if($specs[2] == 1) $img = imagecreatefromgif($file);        //gif
elseif($specs[2] == 2) $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);   //jpg
elseif($specs[2] == 3) $img = imagecreatefrompng($file);    //png
else exit('unsupported file type!');

$newimg = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($img), imagesy($img));
// create a new image with the size of the old one
imagecopy($newimg,$img,0,0,0,0,imagesx($img),imagesy($img));
// copy the old one

imagedestroy($img);
// free the memory

$white = imagecolorallocate($newimg,255,255,255);
imagecolortransparent($newimg,$white);
// make white pixels transparent

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($newimg);
imagedestroy($newimg);
// and finally output the new image
```

Comment: Can you post the code here ? 'code is universal language'.

Comment: Sure, sorry. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the transparent color with the [imagecolortransparent](http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecolortransparent.php) function.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Do you know how to detect the sorrounding color(s) and make them transparent? A single color kind of works but drop shadows in the image need a bit more.

Comment: You have to call `imagesavealpha($image, true);` and then you can create colors like this `$color  = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, $red, $green, $blue, $alpha);`

Comment: How would you know the rgba values?

Comment: The r is the red, the g is the green, the b is the blue "percentage" ranging from 0 to 255. a is the alpha value, i.e. the level of transparency.

Comment: Oh okay. I thought you meant the colors used in the outer gradients such as shades of gray in a 'drop shadow'ed image in your previous comment. This whole thing seems sort of impossible so I quit trying. Thanks anyway :) Cheers.